# Updates to Tour - What to Ask/Not ask?

Tags: discussion, tour

On our [tour page](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) we currently have the following:

#### Ask about...

- Specific issues with hardware recommendations
- Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered

#### Don't ask about...

- Anything not directly related to hardware recommendations
- Questions that are primarily opinion-based
- Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer

What changes should be made, so that we can comfortably point users to the tour page for a quick overview of what we want and what we don't want?

Answer (score 3):

#### Ask about...

- Recommendations for hardware that will meet your *specific* criteria
- Information that will lead to a hardware recommendation

#### Don't ask about...

- Anything not directly related to hardware recommendations or information that will lead to a hardware recommendation
- Technical support of hardware
- Instructions on how to use or configure hardware
- Questions that are primarily opinion-based
- Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer

*This answer has been made a community wiki. Please edit it as you see fit. Once we have moderators appointed, they will be able to utilize this answer to update the tour page.*

Comment: How about "information for use when choosing hardware"?

Comment: For the second bullet in "Ask About"?

Comment: Yep. Just thinking out loud.

Comment: [Hardware](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/50/what-type-of-hardware-is-allowed?rq=1) part is tricky.